# On ATtiny84, why does delay() stop working properly when RadioHead ASK is used?

Tags: attiny

When I call the `delay()` function on the ATtiny84 micro, it delays for the expected time, until I call the `init()` function on an `RH_ASK` object. After this, the micro seems to freeze.

```
#include <RH_ASK.h>
RH_ASK driver();

void setup() {
    delay(100); // works ok
    driver.init();
    delay(100); // freezes a long time (or maybe forever?)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the source code, `RH_ASK.cpp`, I found a commented out macro.

```
// RH_ASK on ATtiny8x uses Timer 0 to generate interrupts 8 times per 
// bit interval. Timer 0 is used by Arduino platform for millis()/micros() 
// which is used by delay()
// Uncomment the define RH_ASK_ATTINY_USE_TIMER1 bellow, if you want to use 
// Timer 1 instead of Timer 0 on ATtiny
// Timer 1 is also used by some other libraries, e.g. Servo. Alway check 
// usage of Timer 1 before enabling this.
// Should be moved to header file
//#define RH_ASK_ATTINY_USE_TIMER1
```

In other words, the default behaviour of RadioHead ASK `init()` is to use **Timer 0**, which causes `delay()` (which uses `millis()`/`micro()`) to behave incorrectly.

**To fix:** Tell RadioHead ASK to use **Timer 1**. Because the `RH_ASK_ATTINY_USE_TIMER1` macro is in the source and not the header (for now), you have to modify the actual RadioHead ASK source file, `RH_ASK.cpp`*. Un-comment the line `#define RH_ASK_ATTINY_USE_TIMER1` which will use **Timer 1** instead of **Timer 0**. Re-compile your code, and `delay()` should start working properly again.

* `RH_ASK.cpp` can be found in `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RadioHead` on Windows, if you installed RadioHead via the Arduino IDE library manager.